# How to enable jQuery UI tooltip for selected elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have a big enterprise web application for which I want to enable jQuery UI tooltip for selected elements. Lot of elements are generated dynamically after the application is initiated and henceeven if I geive id, it does not work. The only way it work is when I do this :

```
var $dj = jQuery.noConflict();
$dj(function() {
    $dj(document).tooltip({
        position: {
            my: 'left center',
            at: 'right+5 center'
        },
        show: 1300,
        hide: 2999
    });
});
```

But this enables tooltip for every element on the application which is not desirable.
Please guide me !

Thanks

Comment: Why do ID's not work?

Comment: May be the page is dynamic and loaded after the application is initiated

Comment: Even if it is dynamic, that still means an ajax call somewhere in your code.  You should know when new elements are being pulled in and you should be able to assign appropriate tooltips then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `items` option to add a selector for event delegation.

**Example:**

```
var $dj = jQuery.noConflict();
$dj(function() {
    $dj(document).tooltip({
        items: 'a.example',
        position: {
            my: 'left center',
            at: 'right+5 center'
        },
        show: 1300,
        hide: 2999
    });
});
```

Where a.example selects the element(s) you want to attach the tooltip widget to.

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/aockfe7o/

**Source:** The [jQuery-UI API reference](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-items)

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but here a.example signifies what ? class name ?

Comment: I need to enable for tooltip for one element and disable for another one. Can I use items attribute to select the specific elements for which I want to show tootlip ?

Comment: Yes. Just select the elements for which you want to enable tooltip for.